# How do I update Geth when using Ethereum Wallet on a windows 10?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

How do I update Geth to the latest version(1.8.10) when I am using Ethereum Wallet on a Windows 10?

It is not prompting me for an update to Geth as I skipped it the first time Ethereum Wallet was opened after an update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

Delete skippedNodeVersion.json file in Ethereum Wallet folder, and run Ethereum Wallet.

Thank you.